# How do i sent dynamic values from form (post method) back to controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am quite new to laravel,

Basically, I have this Form where I am showing values Dynamically, and those values i need to pass into controller again for Delete, but not understanding how to do it.

my blade is as bellow

```
    <div class="col-md-12">
        @if(isset($rtn_user_id))

                @csrf
            <table>

            <tr>


            <td>Customer Name</td> <td>Vechile Name</td>  <td>Imei</td><td>Actions</td>
            </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td> {{$rtn_user_id}}</td> <td></td> <td> {{$rtn_device_name}}</td>  <td>{{$rtn_imei}}</td> <td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        @endif
    </div>
    </form>
```

my operation.delete_imei is like this

so I want to pass the values of $rtn_imei to the controller

> public function delete_imei(Request $request)
> {
>
> ```
>     $post_imei = $request->imei;
>     dd($pos_imei)
>  
>
> }
> ```

web.php

```
 Route::post('deleteimei', 'Operation@delete_imei')->name('operation.delete_imei');
```

Can you please help me with this

Answer (score 1):

You need to issue an HTTP post to `/deleteimei`, which is really an HTML/JS question, depending on how you choose to do it.

Assuming you're not using a JS library which makes life easier, this is how you'll want to do it (change the selectors etc. to suit):

```js
document.getElementsByTagName('button').click = function() {
    xhttp.open('POST', '/deleteimei', true);
    xhttp.send(); 
    location.reload(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

- In Blade File

  @csrf
   
           @if(isset($rtn_user_id))

  ```
           <tr>


           <td>Customer Name</td> <td>Vechile Name</td>  <td>Imei</td><td>Actions</td>
           </tr>

               <tr>

                   <td> {{$rtn_user_id}}</td> <td></td> <td> {{$rtn_device_name}}</td>  <td>{{$rtn_imei}}</td> <td><button formaction="{{route('operation.delete_imei',$rtn_imei)}}" type="submit" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm"><i class="fa fa-trash-o" aria-hidden="true"></i></button></td>
               </tr>

           </table>

       @endif
   </div>
   </form>
  ```
- web.php

Route::delete('deleteimei/{id}', 'Operation@delete_imei')->name('operation.delete_imei');

-In Operation Controller

> public function delete_imei($id)   {
> $post_imei = $id;
> dd($pos_imei)
> $data=DB::delete('delete from delete_imei where id=?',[$id]);
>
> ```
> return redirect(route('index'));
>     }
> ```

Answer (score -1):

i think you should edit your blade like this and this will send your form's data to your controller and you will be suitable for get your request's datas.

```
<form role="form" method="POST" action="{{ route('operation.delete_imei') }}">
@csrf
<div class="col-md-12">
        @if(isset($rtn_user_id))
            <table>

            <tr>


            <td>Customer Name</td> <td>Vechile Name</td>  <td>Imei</td><td>Actions</td>
            </tr>

                <tr>

                    <td> {{$rtn_user_id}}</td> <td></td> <td> {{$rtn_device_name}}</td>  <td>{{$rtn_imei}}</td> <td><button type="button">Delete</button></td>
                </tr>

            </table>

        @endif
    </div>
    </form>
```

Answer (score -1):

if you want to pass some data from blade to controller just put some hidden input in your form and set the value of that with your data you want to pass:

```
<input id="invisible_id" name="invisible" type="hidden" value="{{$data}}">
```